# MVC: How to identify which event on a page calls the controller?

Tags: c#, view, asp.net-mvc-2, controller

I have a `View` that has 2 buttons.

One button called `Create` causes form validation and shows the preview of `SQL Query` to be executed.
Another button called `Confirm`, performs actual execution of the query.

I need to identify in my controller which button was clicked to perform an appropriate action.

This my View:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
   <%:Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>E-Safe Information</legend>
               <div id="Div1" style="height:10px; margin-bottom:10px" runat="server">
                    <%:@Html.ValidationMessage("message") %>   
               </div>
                <%:ViewData["Message"] %>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="editor-label"><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Corporation) %></div></td>
                        <td><div class="editor-field"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Corporation)%></div></td>
                        <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Corporation) %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="editor-label"><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Region) %></div></td>
                        <td><div class="editor-field"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Region, new { @id = "regionTextBox", maxlength = 2 })%></div></td>
                        <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Region) %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="editor-label"><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.PortfolioName) %></div></td>
                        <td><div class="editor-field"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PortfolioName) %></div></td>
                        <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PortfolioName) %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <input type="submit" value="Create" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>            
    <div id="review">
        REVIEW:
        <p>
        <%:ViewData["Review"]%>
        </p>

        <input id="queryReview" type="submit" value="OK"   />
    </div>

<%} %>
```

This is my controller:

```
public class EsafeController : Controller
{

 private ESafeActionService ESafeData { get; set; }

protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    if (ESafeData == null) { ESafeData = new ESafeActionService(); }

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(EsafeModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        EsafeActions eSafe = new EsafeActions(model.Corporation, model.Region, model.PortfolioName);

        if (ESafeData.ValidateData(eSafe))
        {
            ViewData["Review"] = ESafeData.CreateReview(eSafe);

            if (ESafeData.Create(eSafe))
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "E-Safe data created!!!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
           ModelState.AddModelError("message", "The region should be 2 characters long.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("message", "Creation of Data failed. Please correct errors and try again.");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to wrap your content areas in this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("<ActionName>", "<ControllerName>", FormMethod.Get))
{
<input type="submit" value="Create" /> 
}
```

instead of the generic, empty Beginform you have in use.  Then you can specify which parts are controlled by which action in your controller, with the input button included within the braces.

Comment: You may have more than one Html.BeginForm on your page, but keep them from being nested.  You can wrap your table in one, and the DIV ID-"review" in another.

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple solution:

I just need to specify names for both buttons:

```
<input name="create" id="create" type="submit" value="Create" />
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="OK"/>
```

And in my controller I need to call Action method with the following signature:

```
public ActionResult Index(EsafeModel model,string submit, string create)
```

This was the trick...

Hope it will help someone here